# Avoid TextBox vertical stretching

Tags: wpf, height, stretching

How can I avoid TextBox vertical streching in following example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Button Height="40">OK</Button>
  <TextBox Width="200"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I don't have to power to edit tags, but you have a typo on your 'vertical' tag (missing the 'c'). Can you or someone more reputable than me fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the VerticalAlignment Property

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Button Height="40">OK</Button>
  <TextBox Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="40">OK</Button>
        <TextBox Height="40" Width="200"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> Setting the TextWrapping attribute to
>   Wrap causes entered text to wrap to a
>   new line when the edge of the TextBox
>   control is reached, automatically
>   expanding the height of the TextBox
>   control to include room for a new
>   line, if necessary.

So, to fix it, I think you can set `TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap`